# What part of speech is the word 'liking' in the idiom "to one's liking"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

"He has got a house to his liking." In this sentence, what part of speech is **liking**? Is it a gerund or participle?

Comment: _To one's liking_ is an idiom that means _the way one likes it_. The sentence means he's got a house that he likes.

Comment: I'm with JL, and would just add that if you really must parse the clause, then "liking" is probably best analysed as a noun (your gerund). Note that it can be modified by adjectives like "total", "absolute". Note also that "liking" could be replaced with another noun like "satisfaction".

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liking) classes it as a noun in various fixed phrases, but Lexico and Wiktionary leave 'to someone's liking'  (with 'someone's' of course replaceable) as a fixed phrase best not analysed further. // You may want to look through other questions here, where you will meet the CGEL ('lump them all together') and ACGEL (have a gradience with at least 8 identifiable steps') approaches. And probably others.

Comment: Neither *gerund* nor *participle* is a part of speech, which makes this question impossible to answer. Instead ask whether it is a noun or a verb or an adjective, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, the word "liking" is acting as a noun.

The word "one's" should give you a hint. It is a possessive adjective. One can only possess objects (and even in case of qualities in the possessive form, the qualificative word takes the noun form).

You can even replace the word 'liking' with the word 'taste' while retaining the meaning — to one's taste. In this form, it is easier to see what part of speech 'taste' belongs to (the answer being noun). Thus, 'liking' is a noun.

Answer (score -1):

Liking is gerund. I think it is similar to Ram's cow. Liking is used as a noun that is verb+ing (Gerund). Ram's can be written as cow of Ram similarly one's liking can be liking of one.